# How to pass an array of strings from python to C using ctypes and modify that array values in C

Tags: c, arrays, python-3.x, ctypes

Following is the C function **para_trans_test**.

```
void para_trans_test(char x [] [100])
{
    strncpy(x[0],"zzz",100);
}
```

Following is the python code which doesnt work.

```
lib.para_trans_test.argtypes= [ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_char_p)]
numParams=2
L=numpy.array(['xxx','yyy'])
print(type(L))
py_s1 = (ctypes.c_char_p * numParams) ()
py_s1[:]=L
print("py_s1=",py_s1)
lib.para_trans_test(py_s1)
print(py_s1)
```

Initially array L is ('xxx','yyy').

After calling the C function para_trans_test I want array L to be ('zzz','yyy')

Comment: which doesn't work *how*?

Answer (score 3):

The argument type is wrong.  `POINTER(c_char_p)` is equivalent to `char**`.  What is needed is a pointer to a `c_char` array:

Test DLL:

```
#include <string.h>
__declspec(dllexport) void para_trans_test(char x [] [100])
{
    strncpy(x[0],"zzz",100);
}
```

Python:

```
from ctypes import *
lib = CDLL('test')
lib.para_trans_test.argtypes = [POINTER(c_char * 100)]
py_s1 = (c_char * 100 * 2)()
py_s1[0].value = b'xxx'
py_s1[1].value = b'yyy'
print(py_s1[0].value,py_s1[1].value)
lib.para_trans_test(py_s1)
print(py_s1[0].value,py_s1[1].value)
```

Output:

```
b'xxx' b'yyy'
b'zzz' b'yyy'
```