# How to config argtypes for pointer of pointer?

Tags: python, pointers, ctypes

[c code](https://gist.github.com/kobenein/743d9c99751e20e090448568831e53f0) (the code below is wroks!)

```
bool GetDeviceList(unsigned short **DevLists, int *DevCnt);

unsigned short *DevLists[260 * 12];
int DevCnt;
bool ret = GetDeviceList(DevLists, &DevCnt);
```

I reference from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45853191/how-to-pass-an-array-of-strings-from-python-to-c-using-ctypes-and-modify-that-ar)

My python code

```
mydll = CDLL(dll_path)

mydll.GetDeviceList.argtypes = [POINTER(c_ushort*260), POINTER(c_int)]
mydll.GetDeviceList.restype = c_bool

wsList = (c_ushort*260*12)()
RetNum = c_int()
ret = mydll.GetDeviceList(wsList,byref(RetNum))
```

Comment: Are you sure the c code works?  It creates an array of 3120 *uninitialized* short pointers.  Show the C code if you can, or reference docs.  The Python code is creating a 2D array (unsigned short[12][260]), not an array of pointers.  The argtypes should be `POINTER(POINTER(c_ushort))`.

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your reply, here is my code and output (in comment) https://gist.github.com/kobenein/743d9c99751e20e090448568831e53f0.

Comment: That still looks strange to me.  Do you have the code for `GetDeviceList` itself?  The implementation seems weird.

Comment: For what you've shown, `wsList = (POINTER(c_ushort) * (260 * 12))()` and `mydll.GetDeviceList.argtypes = POINTER(POINTER(c_ushort), POINTER(c_int)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the dll is from others.

Comment: I can't imagine why you'd want an array of ushort pointers of length 3120 or how that code even works.

Comment: **unsigned short *DevLists[260 * 12]** is from sample code. I not very familiar with pointer.